# Pick value from object with dynamic key based on input key in Typescript

Tags: typescript, template-literals

So my backend has a JSON like this

```
name: "Hello",
nameTranslations: {nl:"Hallo", en: "Hello", fr: "Bonjour"}
description: "Hello",
descriptionTranslations: {nl:"Hallo", en: "Hello", fr: "Bonjour"}
```

I want to build a function where I'll put in the object and key and it will automatically find the best translation possible. It's easy in Javascript but I want to get Typescript right so I won't be dealing with runtime bugs if I forgot to query the translations (I use GraphQL)

```js
function getText(object, key, language) {
  const best = object[`${key}Translations`][language];
  if (best) {
    return best;
  }

  return object[key];
}
```

Some Typescript requirements I have

- I want only the keys possible of the input object
- I want Typescript to return an error if the key is not available on the object or the 'keyTranslations'

**Update**

<s>Based on the answer of @michmich112 I did go with the following function</s>

```js
function translate<T extends BackendTranslations>(translations: T, fallback: string, language: keyof BackendTranslations) => {
      return translations[language] || fallback;
}

translate(project.nameTranslations, project.name)
```

I will keep the answer open, since I'm still interested if this could work in Typescript

Comment: Whats wrong with @michmich answer?

Comment: It did solve my problem with his suggestion but did not answer the question and I'm still interested if the original function can be typesafe and also follow my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

```js
const json = {
  name: "Hello",
  nameTranslations: { nl: "Hallo", en: "Hello", fr: "Bonjour" },
  description: "Hello",
  descriptionTranslations: { nl: "Hallo", en: "Hello", fr: "Bonjour" }
}

type BackendTranslations = {
  nl: string;
  en: string;
  fr: string;
}


type Raw<T> = T extends `${infer R}Translations` ? R : never

/**
 * Once you will have more specific interface for json
 * this overloading will help you,
 * for now it always returns string , because all properties/nested properties of
 * JSON are strings
 */
//function getText<K extends Raw<keyof Data>>(obj: Data, key: K, language: keyof Translations): K extends string ? Data[`${K}Translations`][keyof Translations] : Data[K];

function getText<
  Data extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends Raw<keyof Data>
>(obj: Data, key: K, language: keyof BackendTranslations) {
  return (
    (obj[`${key}Translations`] as BackendTranslations)[language] || obj[key]
  );
}

const result = getText(json, 'name', 'en') // ok
const result1 = getText(json, 'nameX', 'en') // error
const result2 = getText(json, 'nameTranslations', 'en') // error
const result3 = getText(json, 'description', 'en') // ok
```

Please keep in mind, my solutions works only with TypeScript 4.*

Comment: Really good <3, thanks. If you change it to below code I will accept the answer. It will automatically see which input object is put into the function
```
function getText<
  Data extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends Raw<keyof Data>
>(obj: Data, key: K, language: keyof BackendTranslations) {
  return (
    (obj[`${key}Translations`] as BackendTranslations)[language] || obj[key]
  );
}
```

Comment: @RichardLindhout I have accepted your suggestions. It is Ok now

Comment: Thanks a lot, Typescript 4 is amazing with template literals but I don't understand how to write them, thanks for helping me!

Comment: You can find original PR for template strings, there are a lot of examples. Also take a look on TS docs

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create an interface for your JSON:

```
interface ITranslationData {
  nl: string
  en: string
  fr: string
}

interface ITranslation {
  name: string
  nameTranslations: ITranslationData
  description: string
  descriptionTranslations: ITranslationData
}
```

once you have that you can use types on your function as follows:

```js
function getText(obj: ITranslation, 
  key: keyof ITranslation,
  language: keyof ITranslationData): string {
  const best = obj[key][language];
  if (best) {
    return best;
  }

  return obj[key];
}
```

this will require your key to be exact which means you will not be able to do `const best = object[`${key}Translations`][language];`

it also means you can write your code in a single line:

```
function getText(obj: ITranslation, 
  key: keyof ITranslation,
  language: keyof ITranslationData): string {
  return obj[key][language] || obj[key];
}
```

Comment: I think I agree with the sentiment to use a different function

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions!